# Excluding all /api routes in Nest.js to serve React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, routes, nestjs

I'm developing a back-end in Nest.js which should serve React generated `index.html` on all root-level routes (`/about`, `/contact-us` and so on) but not on the ones starting with `/api`. This is what I currently do in the `AppController`:

```
@Get('/')
@Get('/contact')
@Get('/about-us')
fileServingRoutes(@Res() res: Response) {
  return res.sendFile('index.html', { root: AppModule.getStaticAssetsRootPath() });
}
```

Is there any way to do this without manually defining all routes which have to send file back?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend following Bo's great [article](https://medium.com/@bo.vandersteene/use-nest-as-your-server-side-application-with-an-angular-frontend-540b0365bfa3) on serving SPAs. The setup has Angular in mind but is the same for a React app.

### Gist

Define a middleware function that redirects all routes except `/api` to your `index.html`.

```
@Middleware()
export class FrontendMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req, res, next) {
    const { url } = req;
    if (url.indexOf('/api') === 1) {
      next();
    } else {
      res.sendFile(resolvePath('index.html'));
    }
  }
}
```

Register it for all routes in your `AppModule`:

```
export class ApplicationModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(FrontendMiddleware).forRoutes(
      {
        path: '/**',
        method: RequestMethod.ALL,
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I slightly modified Kim's solution for my needs (I'm using version 5.8.0) so in case you get the error that your middleware doesn't implement `NestMiddleware` interface properly (because of the `resolve` method), you can use [functional middleware](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware#functional-middleware);

```
export function FrontendMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  const { baseUrl } = req;
  if (baseUrl.indexOf('/api') === 0) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.sendFile(<path to your index.html file>);
  }
}
```

I also used `baseUrl` instead of `url` property which returned `/` when I tried to access `/api` route.

Comment: What nest version are you on? My solution should be in nest v6 syntax (it changed from v5). I didn't test it though.

Comment: I'm on the version 5.8.0. Thanks for clarification, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok, I see. :-) The linked article uses nest v5 syntax, that's why I used the v6 syntax in the post. You should consider updating, it's not a huge effort but adds some nice new features (and e.g. the middleware syntax is a bit clearer ;-)) https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider using [@nestjs/serve-static package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestjs/serve-static). It helps you serve static content such as React and other SPAs.

The configuration has an option to exclude the routes you want to exclude.

For example, you may use prefix your API routes with "api":

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('api')
```

and use ServeStaticModule from @nestjs/serve-static to serve your React.

A basic configuration in AppModule:

```js
...
@Module({
  imports: [
    ServeStaticModule.forRoot({
      rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client'),
      exclude: ['api/*'],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```